# Problema Angular *ngFor con array objetos desde funcion

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy intentando hacer el uso de Angular Material MatSelect pero estoy usando un array de objetos que obtengo desde una función

Ejercicio básico que funciona

archivo html

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

archivo ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
  ];
}
```

lo que quiero hacer y no funciona, de hecho la aplicación web se queda congelada y no muestra errores en consola

archivo html

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of data()" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

archivo ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  data(): Food[] {
    return [
      {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
      {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
      {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
    ];
  }
}
```

como dato extra, el siguiente ejemplo si funciona en el cual en la función retorno un arreglo simple de string y no un arreglo de objetos

archivo html

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of data()" [value]="food">
      {{food}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

archivo ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
  ];

  foods2 = ['Steak', 'Pizza', 'Tacos'];

  data(): string[] {
    return ['Steak', 'Pizza', 'Tacos'];
  }
}
```

Comment: El ngFor itera sobre arrays, no sobre funciones, lo que podrias hacer es que la dentro de la funcion le asignas a un array.

this.newArray = (el array que devuelve la función)

luego iteras es sobre esa respuesta *ngFor="let food of newArray"

Comment: opciones tengo, básicamente quisiera saber si esto es posible hacerlo considerando que el uso de funciones es posible si la funcion retorna un arreglo simple de strings, pero no un arreglo de objetos

Comment: Tu error debe estar en otra parte. La función retorna bien los datos. Mira [este ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dcz1ht?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: el ejercicio se ve bien, el problema debe ser con angular-material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguien me dio la respuesta:

> La aplicación se congela porque mat-option intenta hacer render de todos los cambios una y otra vez sin parar, esto sucede porque se está usando una función que retorna un objeto "complejo" y no un objeto simple (string array), entonces esta en todo momento ejecutando la función para saber si hay cambios

Solución:

usar trackBy

archivo html

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let food of data(); trackBy: trackedValue"
      [value]="food.value"
    >
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

archivo ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}

  data(): any[] {
    console.log('Get value');
    return [
      { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
      { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
      { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
    ];
  }

  trackedValue(index, item) {
    return item.value;
  }
}
```